# How to fix JButton.setBackground(new Color())? Alpha is not working properly

Tags: java, swing

Whenever I hover the mouse over a JButton with the setBackground method set to a new color with the alpha set to 10 it gets darker. The problem is when I take the mouse off of the button it still stays just as dark as if i were hovering over the button. On top of that when I hover over the button again it makes the button even darker.

I'm trying to make the button stay translucent so I can see the panel in the background.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Test
{
    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p;
    private JButton b;
    public Test()
    {
        f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setSize(400, 200);
        p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        b = new JButton();
        b.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0, 10));
        p.add(b);
        f.add(p);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

What I want is to create a translucent button so I can see the panel in the background.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JButton alpha background change with mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162510/jbutton-alpha-background-change-with-mouseover)

Answer (score 0):

you should declare two color active and hover, and add MouseListener, where you change background color and repaint the frame

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FrameTest {
    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p;
    private JButton b;

    private static final Color activeButtonBackground = new Color(255, 0, 0, 10);
    private static final Color hoverButtonBackground = new Color(255, 0, 0, 20);

    public FrameTest() {
        f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setSize(400, 200);
        p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        b = new JButton();
        b.setBackground(activeButtonBackground);
        b.addMouseListener(getMouseListeners());
        p.add(b);
        f.add(p);
    }

    private MouseListener getMouseListeners() {
        return new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                //on button released
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                //on button pressed
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                //on move mouse off the button
                b.setBackground(activeButtonBackground);
                f.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                //on button hover
                b.setBackground(hoverButtonBackground);
                f.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                //on mouse clicked - pressed and released
            }
        };
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FrameTest t = new FrameTest();
        t.f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this appears to solve the problem, it is not really the best solution. 1) When a property of a Swing component is changed, the component repaints itself automatically. The fact that you have to invoke repaint() of the frame to get the button to paint properly is a problem. 2) The real problem is that Swing does not handle transparent backgrounds properly. Read the solution from the link in the comment. 3) You are overriding the default rollover functionality of the button.